# Slice video frames in time

Tags: image, matlab, video, video-processing, volume

Considering all video frames of a video in time (`t`) as volume, I have to decompose them into set of 2d slices in time i.e `I(x,t)` (Slice volume along x and t) and `I(y,t)` (slice volume along y and t). How can I achieve this in matlab? I am not able to figure out how to do this slicing?

Edit: Code so far

```
vid='Orca vs Great White Shark.avi';
vidobj=mmreader(vid);
numofframes=get(vidobj,'numberOfFrames');
disp(numofframes);
for i=1:25:numofframes
  vidframe=read(vidobj,i);
end
for k=1:numofframes
  mov(k).cdata = read(vidobj,k);
end
```

So far I have read the video and saved the frames in vidframes. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
A = rand(3,3,3)
```

Terminal:

```
A(:,:,1) =

    0.8147    0.9134    0.2785
    0.9058    0.6324    0.5469
    0.1270    0.0975    0.9575


A(:,:,2) =

    0.9649    0.9572    0.1419
    0.1576    0.4854    0.4218
    0.9706    0.8003    0.9157


A(:,:,3) =

    0.7922    0.0357    0.6787
    0.9595    0.8491    0.7577
    0.6557    0.9340    0.7431
```

Now I assume the 3rd dimension is time. To get a slice you need to use the squeeze function:

```
squeeze(A(1,:,:))'
```

terminal:

```
ans =

    0.8147    0.9134    0.2785
    0.9649    0.9572    0.1419
    0.7922    0.0357    0.6787
```

squeeze(A(:,1,:)) will give the first column in time.

Comment: Hi.Thanks for the answer.sorry to ask but I'm pretty new to this. Can you please tell me how can I represent x,y,t of my video in such matrix representation?

Comment: Check this :
http://www.mathworks.in/help/imaq/bringing-image-data-into-the-matlab-workspace.html

Comment: @SriduttNayak I have read all the frames of video using `frames=read(videoobject)`, how do I read it as a matrix like above?

Comment: frame will have a matrix you'd need if you use getsnapshot. 
I guess in the above case you'd be creating a handle (Not sure check) so you may have to see how to use it. Check here :http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/mmreaderclass.html


If you use getsnapshot, after first instance of frame = getsnapshot(vid); , type keyboard this will put code in debug mode. Now in command window try doing <whos frame> <imshow(frame)> after you have understood, continue the run using F5. Remember to remove "keyboard" for next run.

Comment: Thanks @SriduttNayak I will check and come back in few minsutes. Thanks

Comment: Getsnapshot is for snapshot coming from a source like webcam.How do I use it for a video stored already? @SriduttNayak